# `join` is also a function of endofunctor?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads

Every monad is a endofunctor.

`bind` of monad is a composition of `fmap` and `join`.

`fmap` is a function of endofunctor.

Then, is it safe to say `join` is also a function of endofunctor?

Comment: No. No it isn't safe to say that. Join is for un-nesting monadic structures. Your logic is flawed. Equivalent to saying 1. crowns are a property of princesses. 2. All princesses are female. 3. Therefor crowns are properties of females. While every monad is a functor, not every functor is a monad in the same way not every female is a princess.

Comment: Oh, sure. I find myself terribly wrong. join does not even take a parameter of Function...

Answer (score 2):

An endofunctor is a pair of mappings: one that maps a type to another type, and one that maps a function to another function. In this sense, the endofunctor "has" `fmap`, as `fmap` is the function-to-function mapping.

A monad is a triplet consisting of an endofunctor and two natural transformations. One of the natural transformations is `return :: a -> m a`. The other, in Haskell, is `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. `join ms = ms >>= id`, but we could just as easily say that `join :: m (m a) -> m a` is the natural transformation associated with the monad and that `m >>= f = join (fmap f m)`. In that case, the *monad* (not the endofunctor) "has" `join` as a function.